# Union All Command in SQL

Tags: sql, database, select, null

```
SELECT  a.VPNID||'|'||a.PUBLICNUMBER||'|'||a.PRIVATENUMBER   from virtualterminal a 
UNION ALL
SELECT  b.VPNID||'|'||b.PUBLICNUMBER||'|'||b.PRIVATENUMBER||'|'||b.PROFILEID from terminal b;
```

This is the code , but  in the first statement  as you can see there is no `PROFILEID`  column. I would like to write " null " to that column because we don't know the `PROFILEID` of them. How can I write "null" to that column  ?

Comment: There is only one column in your output, and it is a character column. Just put `|| '|null'` in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
SELECT  a.VPNID||'|'||a.PUBLICNUMBER||'|'||a.PRIVATENUMBER||'|'||'NULL'
from  virtualterminal a 
UNION ALL
SELECT  b.VPNID||'|'||b.PUBLICNUMBER||'|'||b.PRIVATENUMBER||'|'||b.PROFILEID 
from terminal b;
```

Comment: He'll also need an alias on the "NULL" or NULL to retain a column heading of PROFILEID or put it second in the UNION

Comment: @StephLocke No, I request to please read the Question once again.

Comment: OP said ' no PROFILEID column. I would like to write " null " to that column '  - presumed that meant he wanted to keep the column called PROFILEID - no worries if he didn't!  Your code is perfectly correct, but thought he made need it aliased too

Comment: @StephLocke Actually OP is Concatenating **`3 Columns`** seperated by **`|`**. but he doesn't have **`Column 3`** in First table, so he want to write a **`NULL`** values.

Comment: ahh...those are concatenation pipes, I thought they were an odd delimiter specific to whatever RDBMS he was using. d'oh! so he definitely won't want to alias just that column, although I'd recommend aliasing anyway for the whole thing just to give it a nice name that indicates purpose